# rsync unknown option from bash script execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, lubuntu

I'm trying to simply sync a folder using rsync over my local network from my computer in front of me to the destination computer.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script will sync from my Macbook Dropbox/scripts/ folder to ruth@10.0.0.9 @ Norms house"

OPTIONS="--recursive --ignore-existing --progress"
SRC_DIR="~/Dropbox/scripts/"
DST_DIR="ruth@10.0.0.9:~/scripts/"
rsync "$OPTIONS" "$SRC_DIR" "$DST_DIR"
```

To give myself write privileges

```
chmod +x nameofscript.sh
```

When I run it, it outputs:

```
rsync: --recursive --ignore-existing --progress: unknown option
```

How do I properly store these options and run it as a script?

Comment: Please don’t add your solution to your question; if you feel the accepted answer isn’t complete enough, you can suggest an edit to that, or add your own separate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By quoting `"$OPTIONS"`, the shell is passing it to rsync as a single string, so rsync is trying to find a single option named `"--recursive --ignore-existing --progress"`, which obviously doesn't exist, since these are three separate options.

This should fix it for you:

```
rsync $OPTIONS "$SRC_DIR" "$DST_DIR"
```

---

A better option might be to use a bash array to store your options.

```
OPTIONS=(
    --recursive
    --ignore-existing
    --progress
)
# ...
rsync "${OPTIONS[@]}" "$SRC_DIR" "$DST_DIR"
```

The advantage of using an array is that then you are able to introduce items that include spaces, if any are necessary.

Comment: The bash array works great to store the options, I've edited my original with the correct script. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome @Kaiya, I'm glad this worked for you!

Comment: The array approach also works nicely with trailing comments, i.e. `--flag  # Added because…`.